# What is a clove of garlic?

Tags: garlic

If a recipe calls for 8 whole cloves of garlic, does it mean 8 whole garlics? Or does it mean 8 of the wedges?

Comment: http://www.mmmgarlic.com/clove-garlic-vs-head-garlic/

Comment: [Garlic on English Language & Usage](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/6893).

Comment: This question just naturally begs for a photo in the best answer.

Comment: When the recipe says "whole", it may mean to keep each clove whole i.e. not sliced or chopped or minced.

Answer (score 65):

Each "wedge" is a clove.  The entire garlic is called a "head".

Comment: The heads are also sometimes called bulbs.

Comment: And, let's face it, they are not all that standard, so a degree of common sense and how much you like garlic need to be applied to recipes that are written this way, or the results will be very different with large or small cloves...

Comment: It may be easier to remember this distinction if you realize that the word "clove", as applied to a "wedge" of garlic, [comes from the same root](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/clove#Etymology_2) as the verb "cleave" (and the corresponding participle "cloven", meaning "split" or "divided").

Comment: It's very important not to mix this up! While at college one of my flatmates made a spag bol using 2 bulbs rather than 2 wedges. Not to be repeated :)

Comment: @IlmariKaronen but of course not from the same root as [the verb "cleave" meaning "cling, adhere or stick fast to something"](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cleave#Verb_2) ...

Comment: @Fetchezlavache I had to search for "[spag bol](https://www.google.com/search?q=spag+bol)" to find that it meant "spaghetti bolognese."  Now the mental picture is complete.  :)

Comment: Apologies mskfisher :)

Comment: Related: if you're using it for a recipe, a clove of garlic produces about a teaspoon of minced garlic.

Comment: @Fetchezlavache, a friend of mine made that mistake for at least a year and was amazed that his friends never came for dinner twice. (He turned into a great cook later.)

Answer (score 13):

For easy reference , I am posting the picture directly here.
Reference : [LINK](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6886/what-do-you-call-a-bunch-of-garlic-when-you-dont-remove-the-cloves/6893#6893)

[image: What is a garlic head and garlic clove ?]

Comment: The strings also come one bulb wide in a plastic mesh.